# Override default woocommerce_get_cancel_order_url_raw

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to start by saying im not developer my self at all, but im trying to come up with a solution my self. Im trying to override the woocommerce_get_cancel_order_url_raw taht is inside public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php from the functions.php file of the template so it does not get overriden when updating plugins. I want to be able to define a url (in this case the home page, but maybe it is important to mention im using WPML so there are more than one lang, but if it is too complicated, there is a redirection in place based on the user geolocation). I found this function, but seem not to be working or at least i cant make it work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cancel_order_url_raw', 'paypal_canceled_redirect' );
function paypal_canceled_redirect(){
    wp_redirect(home_url()); // REDIRECT PATH
    exit;
}
```

Thanks
Kind regards

Comment: The purpose of the `woocommerce_get_cancel_order_url_raw` filter is to modify that URL _in string form_. Directly calling `wp_redirect` in there makes no sense. You need to _return_ the new URL value from this function.

Comment: Hey! first of all thanks for taking your time on answering me. I'm not 100% sure I understood your answer, although i somehow get the idea. Now.... what can i do? because my problem is that due to the theme im using when someone goes to paypal and comes back it goes to an super ugly page, I would like to redirect people to homepage, is that possible? does that make sense?

Comment: _“Now.... what can i do?”_ - that what I just told you - _return_ the URL value from the function, instead of trying to redirect elsewhere. `function paypal_canceled_redirect(){ return home_url(); }`

Comment: I see what you mean now!!! ok it does work, thanks so much man/woman, you saved me, and you teach me some new stuff you are a star.

Comment: I summed up the content of the comments in an answer, feel free to mark as “solution” :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `woocommerce_get_cancel_order_url_raw` filter is to modify that URL *in string form*. Directly calling `wp_redirect` in there makes no sense. (This is a value that gets passed to the external payment gateway service, so that the gateway can redirect the user back to your site if they cancel the process.)

You need to return the new URL value from this function.

```
/* Paypal cancel order redirect */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cancel_order_url_raw', 'paypal_canceled_redirect' );
function paypal_canceled_redirect(){ 
  return home_url();
}
```

Comment: This is the short answer, and it is the correct answer, although i published the full answer just in case someone like me with no coding abilities see this post it can copy and paste directly. Feel free to add the whole code then i will gladly mark it as answer. Once again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CBroe, he pointed me into the right direction, and more over helped me implementing the solution. This would be:

```
/* Paypal cancel order redirect */
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cancel_order_url_raw', 'paypal_canceled_redirect' );
    function paypal_canceled_redirect(){ 
                           return home_url();
    }
```

Comment: Hola Andres… The answer of @Cbroe should be the accepted (upvoted) answer even if the add_filter part was missing. You should remove your answer then…